# Which breaks first, Mockito or Java Generics?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I have a handy function I'm working on that traces the time it takes to do an operation and sends that off to our monitoring service. The idea was to be minimally intrusive into our main code base as possible, so I thought I'd have it take in a `Runnable` or `Supplier<T>` and execute that itself.

```java
  public <T> T recordElapsedTime(
      Builder measurementBundleBuilder,
      DistributionMetric distributionMetric,
      Supplier<T> operation) {
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = stopwatchProvider.get();

    stopwatch.start();
    final T result = operation.get();
    stopwatch.stop();

    record(
        measurementBundleBuilder
            .addMeasurement(distributionMetric, stopwatch.elapsed().toMillis())
            .build());
    return result;
  }
```

You call it like this, for example

```java
    List<WorkspaceResponse> workspaces =
        logsBasedMetricService.recordElapsedTime(
            MeasurementBundle.builder().addTag(MetricLabel.OPERATION_NAME, "getWorkspaces"),
            DistributionMetric.WORKSPACE_OPERATION_TIME,
            workspaceService::getWorkspaces);
```

And there's a runnable version that's the same, but returns void.

So the fun begins when I have to mock the service exposing this function.

These are going into common code paths, so lots of test cleanup. Mock object methods return `null` by default, so you'd lose your created Workspace or whatever other precious object.

The mocking I have now looks like this:

```java
    doAnswer(invocation -> ((Supplier) invocation.getArgument(2)).get())
        .when(mockLogsBasedMetricService)
        .recordElapsedTime(
            any(MeasurementBundle.Builder.class),
            any(DistributionMetric.class),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Supplier<Workspace>>any());
```

So the question now is, can I mock this behavior for any `Supplier<T>` argument? I've tried just using a naked `Supplier` and `Supplier<Object>`, but to no avail. I really don't want to do this for every supplier type.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Did you try it?

Comment: There is an overload actually, but that takes in a `Runnable` instead of a supplier. I didn't see how to make a Supplier<Void> take in a void function.

I don't see how to call `get()` without a supplier object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `doAnswer` in a method, this should work generically:

```
<T> void setupAnswer (/* whatever args */) {
  doAnswer(invocation -> ((Supplier<T>) invocation.getArgument(2)).get())
      .when(mockLogsBasedMetricService)
      .recordElapsedTime(
          any(MeasurementBundle.Builder.class),
          any(DistributionMetric.class),
          ArgumentMatchers.<Supplier<T>>any());
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will do the job, and is much cleaner than what I was expecting. Thanks.

I suppose another answer would be to use a fake instead of a mock since I need to call this in so many places.